# Тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "Вижу — двое, под три метра, косматые." После "вижу" что все-таки лучше поставить: тире или двоеточие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это от контекста зависит. Ну или от авторского замысла. 
Если фраза не несет особой эмоциональной нагрузки, то, наверное, все-таки двоеточие.
Впрочем, весьма вероятно, что тут именно такой акцент: внезапности, испуга. Так что и тире смотрится вполне органично. 
Это имхо, можно спорить.)))